# ggplot2 not using entire plot area

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create the following graph with the following code:

```
x = sample(0:1,10,replace = TRUE)
y = sample(0:1,10,replace = TRUE)
df = data.frame(x,y)
dfSummary<-ddply(df, "x", summarise, sdbar = sd(y), ybar = mean(y))
ggplot(dfSummary, aes(x,y = ybar))+
    geom_bar(stat="identity",fill="dark blue")+
    geom_errorbar(ymin=(pmax(0,dfSummary$ybar-dfSummary$sdbar)),ymax=(pmin(dfSummary$ybar+dfSummary$sdbar,1)))+
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1),breaks=seq(0,1,.1)) + 
    theme(panel.grid = element_blank()) + 
    theme(panel.background =element_blank())+
    scale_x_discrete( breaks= c(0,1), limits = c(0,1),labels= c("x = 0", "x = 1")) +
    ylab("Proportion of objective responders")
```

The resulting image which you can see below shows a plot where the two bars for x=0 and x=1 take up half of the y-axis length (on the left) but do not fill out the entire plot area.

I'd really appreciate any insight into how to make the barplot be displayed across the width of the image.

[image]

I tried what @heroka suggested by changing x to a factor.  Now the code looks like this:

```
x = sample(0:1,10,replace = TRUE)
y = sample(0:1,10,replace = TRUE)
df = data.frame(x,y)
df$x = as.factor(df$x)
dfSummary<-ddply(df, "x", summarise, sdbar = sd(y), ybar = mean(y))
ggplot(dfSummary, aes(x,y = ybar))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",fill="dark blue")+
  geom_errorbar(ymin=(pmax(0,dfSummary$ybar-dfSummary$sdbar)),ymax=(pmin(dfSummary$ybar+dfSummary$sdbar,1)))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1),breaks=seq(0,1,.1)) + 
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank()) +
  theme(panel.background =element_blank())+
  scale_x_discrete( breaks= c(0,1), limits = c(0,1),labels= c("x = 0", "x = 1")) +
  ylab("Proportion of objective responders")
```

And I get the image [Box plot with incorrect labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bn4b8.jpg) where you can see that the labels "x=0" and "x=1" are now not in the right place.  "x=1" is under the wrong bar and "x=0" does not even appear.  How can I fix this?

Comment: You might want to consider setting x as a factor here, I think the issue arises from mixing continuous and discrete axis.

Answer (score 1):

As Heroka mentioned, make your `x` variable a factor.
Your scale problem is because in your `scale_x_discrete` you are specifying numeric breaks & limits which you don't need any more (if you `as.numeric` your `x` factor you'll get 1 and 2, not 0 and 1, so that's why the 1 label is lined up with x=0).

```
p <- ggplot(dfSummary, aes(x,y = ybar))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",fill="dark blue")+
  geom_errorbar(ymin=(pmax(0,dfSummary$ybar-dfSummary$sdbar)),ymax=(pmin(dfSummary$ybar+dfSummary$sdbar,1)))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1),breaks=seq(0,1,.1)) + 
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank()) +
  theme(panel.background =element_blank())+
  ylab("Proportion of objective responders")
```

You can either:

1. omit the 'breaks' and 'limits' arguments

   ```
   p + scale_x_discrete(labels=c("x=0", "x=1"))
   ```
2. Since `x` is a factor anyway, just make the value the labels 'x=0' and 'x=1' instead of '0' and '1'

   ```
   dfSummary$x <- factor(c('x=0', 'x=1'))
   # just use the code for `p` above to make your graph, no scale_x_discrete
   #  needed.
   ```